# Page does not seem to load assets in containers

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am running functional tests with nightwatch.js. I have things working fine in my local environment, but when I run the test in a container environment (so I can hook it up to my CI pipeline and run it on every release), I'm either getting an issue with assets loading or an issue with the screenshots.

When the test fails, it takes a screenshot, and I have the screenshot directory mapped to the host so I can see the screenshot easily. Without fail, I am getting an unstyled page in my screenshot, with the page javascript not seeming to have run. I suspect the page is really not loading assets of any kind: not my CSS being served from the same container, nor my client JS, and that's why the test is failing.

I have tried both chromedriver and firefox in a selenium container, and my app is a node.js app running in a container as well; when I connect to the container my app is in using a browser, I see exactly what I expect to see. I have tried both selenium standalone images and blueimp's images.  A test run against an external website runs fine.

ETA: I got my app to dump a message when it sees a request, and it's only seeing one request: the main url. No asset requests.

Comment: can you show some example? Also possible any kind of JS error is there? Are you running headless chrome or normal chrome?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I haven't done any modifications to the stock selenium container, so I assume it's running a headless chrome but I'm not actually sure. I can show the screenshot, but it's just an unstyled page with some buttons on it since my Bootstrap didn't load. I can't seem to get any JS errors out of nightwatch, and like I said, when I use a real Chrome browser, I get the page exactly as I expect

Comment: So you are not using headless if you are using stock selenium container. You can enable VNC also in selenium docker containers and then see what is actually happening. You need to use `selenium/standalone-chrome-debug` for the same

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be unrelated. Something had gone wrong during my asset compilation step, so the assets were 404ing on my dev machine but not in my other test environments. My apologies.